# Index / check values of a matrix by factors

Tags: r, indexing, boolean

Given a df:

df1:

```
        x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10 x11 x12
Group 1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   0.7 5   15  16  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   1   5   5   61  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   1.2 28  6   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   1.2 44  10  66  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   1.2 6   8   59  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   1.4 23  18  38  5   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 1 0   2   16  16  107 1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 2 0   2.9 0   3   63  4   2   1   0   2   0   0
Group 2 0   3.2 1   5   35  5   1   1   2   0   0   0
Group 2 0   4.3 1   9   68  7   4   1   0   0   0   0
Group 2 0   4.6 0   7   51  5   4   3   1   1   1   1
Group 2 0   4.6 1   6   22  4   2   4   1   1   1   1
Group 3 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   1.5 0   1   25  2   2   1   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   2   0   2   99  3   0   0   0   1   0   0
Group 3 0   2.2 0   2   44  2   1   2   1   2   2   2
Group 3 0   2.6 0   1   58  2   1   1   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   2.9 5   5   83  0   1   2   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   3.3 1   2   36  3   1   2   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   3.4 3   4   78  7   3   1   0   1   0   0
Group 3 0   3.5 0   5   87  4   4   2   0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   4.6 0   4   52  3   1   2   2   1   0.5 0.5
Group 4 0   2.9 1   5   104 5   4   1   0   0   0   0
Group 4 0   3.1 1   1   60  0   2   1   2   0   0   0
Group 4 0   3.6 0   5   55  4   4   2   1   0   0   0
Group 4 0   5   1   8   36  6   3   2   1   0   0   0
```

I would like to factor this by another df of requirements for each group:

df2:

```
        x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  x10 x11 x12
Group 1 0   3.5 100 2   1   1   0.5 0.5 0   0   0   0
Group 2 0   4   90  2.5 1.5 1   0.6 0.6 0   0   0   0
Group 3 0   4   60  3   2   1   0.7 0.7 0   0   0   0
Group 4 0   5   50  4   3   2   1   1   0   0   0   0
```

For example, df < df2 would create a boolean matrix for every value of df1 as factored by the value of its group in df2 or not - example df1:

```
        x1      x2      x3      x4      x5      x6      x7      x8      x9      x10     x11     x12
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
Group 1 FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

The problem is that the number of members in each group changes, so this needs to be able to handle a dynamic size of each group.

Also the first column can be either row names or an independent column.

Comment: What do you numerically mean by "meeting a requirement" ? Why for instance column x4 is true for group1 in the first row, but false in the second row ?

Comment: Clarified a bit - but to be more explicit:

`df1["x4","Group 1"]` will return "TRUE" if below the value for `df2["x4","Group 1"]` - which in this case, the first element in `df1` is 0 which is lower than 2, so "TRUE" and the second element 15 is higher than 2 so "FALSE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach :

```
# prepend DF2 column names with "R."
names(DF2)[-1] <- paste('R',names(DF2)[-1],sep='.')
# merge DF1 and DF2
DF3 <- merge(DF1,DF2,by='Group',all.x = TRUE)
# compute the matrix of requirements satisfaction
bools <- DF3[,names(DF1)[-1]] < DF3[,paste('R',names(DF1)[-1],sep='.')]
# construct the final DF
DFResult <- data.frame(Group=DF3$Group,bools)
```

DFResult :

```
> DFResult
     Group    x1    x2   x3    x4    x5    x6    x7    x8    x9   x10   x11   x12
1  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8  Group 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
9  Group 2 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
10 Group 2 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
11 Group 2 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
12 Group 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
13 Group 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
14 Group 2 FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
15 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
16 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
17 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
18 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
19 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
20 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
21 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
22 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
23 Group 3 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
24 Group 3 FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
25 Group 4 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
26 Group 4 FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
27 Group 4 FALSE  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
28 Group 4 FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Code to recreate your input data :

```
DF1 <- read.csv(text=
"Group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12
Group 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,0.7,5,15,16,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,1,5,5,61,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,1.2,28,6,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,1.2,44,10,66,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,1.2,6,8,59,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,1.4,23,18,38,5,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 1,0,2,16,16,107,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 2,0,2.9,0,3,63,4,2,1,0,2,0,0
Group 2,0,3.2,1,5,35,5,1,1,2,0,0,0
Group 2,0,4.3,1,9,68,7,4,1,0,0,0,0
Group 2,0,4.6,0,7,51,5,4,3,1,1,1,1
Group 2,0,4.6,1,6,22,4,2,4,1,1,1,1
Group 3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,1.5,0,1,25,2,2,1,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,2,0,2,99,3,0,0,0,1,0,0
Group 3,0,2.2,0,2,44,2,1,2,1,2,2,2
Group 3,0,2.6,0,1,58,2,1,1,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,2.9,5,5,83,0,1,2,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,3.3,1,2,36,3,1,2,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,3.4,3,4,78,7,3,1,0,1,0,0
Group 3,0,3.5,0,5,87,4,4,2,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,4.6,0,4,52,3,1,2,2,1,0.5,0.5
Group 4,0,2.9,1,5,104,5,4,1,0,0,0,0
Group 4,0,3.1,1,1,60,0,2,1,2,0,0,0
Group 4,0,3.6,0,5,55,4,4,2,1,0,0,0
Group 4,0,5,1,8,36,6,3,2,1,0,0,0")

DF2 <- read.csv(text=
"Group,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12
Group 1,0,3.5,100,2,1,1,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0
Group 2,0,4,90,2.5,1.5,1,0.6,0.6,0,0,0,0
Group 3,0,4,60,3,2,1,0.7,0.7,0,0,0,0
Group 4,0,5,50,4,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0")
```